# Disable brackets placement after autocompletion in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have re-installed VS Code and cannot find a setting which disables placing brackets after function/method autocompletion. In addition, I use Jedi language server and Pylint.

Brackets are added after autocompletion:

[image: Added after autocompletion]

I expected brackets to not be automatically added when completing functions:

[image: Expected]

Comment: these images should be code blocks. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the following in one of your [setting.json files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true
```

Find it, and then either set it to `false`, or remove it, since the default value is `false`.

The setting's description:

> Add parentheses to function completions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got Unknown Configuration Setting, probably because I am not using Pylance but Jedi instead.

Comment: @ Entl_   This is useful configuration. Do you completely copy the content in the answer and have Python extensions?